# Solving Summations of Two Raised Numbers

Tags: summation, education, geometric-series

I apologize if the title is incorrect, I am not exactly sure how to describe this.
I am trying to solve a summation:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{3^{-k}7^{n-k}}
$$
I am not sure how I would go about solving this. I considered distributing the summation to each term but using wolfram gave me different answers. Either way I do not want to rely on calculators to solve sums like these. How can I go about solving a sum like this?

And in general, is there a place I can read more about summation properties?

Thank you

Comment: Hint:  this is just a geometric series with a little camouflage.

Comment: Perhaps look up "geometric series".

Comment: @lulu crap... Is it cause $3^{(-n)}$ is constant for the entire sum? Then its just a summation over $7^{(n-k)}$ which is just a geometric series?

Comment: @lulu Ah wait! I messed up... I believe it should be $3^{-k}$ How would that change the summation since it is no longer constant?

Comment: $7^n$ is constant over the entire sum.

Comment: Compare to $\sum\left(\frac{1}{21}\right)^k$

Comment: Oooo yes I see now thank you! @lulu

Comment: Yes! Thank you! @JMoravitz